# Java 8 on RHEL 6 - what to do?

Tags: java-8, rhel, rhel6

The Oracle page that specifies Java 8 system requirements on Linux is ambiguous (at least to me)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html

It states that

Red Hat Enterprise Linux    x86 (32-bit)    6.x 1.8.0
Red Hat Enterprise Linux    x64 (64-bit)    6.x 1.8.0   Only 64-bit JRE is supported

Does this mean that 32bit is supported for JDK and JRE but 64bit is only supported for JRE? That does look a bit odd.

For RHEL 7 it says that only 64bit JRE is supported. No mention of 32bit.

I thought that the only difference between JDK and JRE was the tools. Surely the JVM is the same.

I have some processes that really need to be on 32bit for a few months longer until some native libs are updated. I have a mixture of RHEL 5.5 and 6.x.

Comment: Footnote says "On 64-bit operating systems (OSs), both 32-bit and 64-bit Java virtual machines (JVMs) are certified, except where noted.", that's probably what this limitation is about

Comment: So I could run a JDK but not a JRE. That seems odd. Thanks